# The correct way to write javadocs

Tags: java, constructor, javadoc

I have been given the exiciting job to add some javadoc to some code. 
so here is my Q:

what is the right way to write javadoc for this constructor.

```
public Match(int MatchID, int MatchRound, int HomeTeamID, int GuestTeamID, boolean IsPlayed) {
    this.isPlayed = IsPlayed;
    this.matchID = MatchID;
    this.matchRound = MatchRound;
    this.homeTeamID = HomeTeamID;
    this.guestTeamID = GuestTeamID;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have an IDE that's doing the job for you?

Comment: Its worth knowing the javadoc tool [reference docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/). Are you having a specific issue with existing documents, or do you just want to learn how to write documentation?

Comment: You should also name your parameter variables starting with lowercase because that's the Java convention.  The parameters can already be disambiguated by "this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the formatted Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Constructor for creating a new match.
 * @param MatchID the id of the match
 * @param MatchRound the round for the match
 * @param HomeTeamID the id of the home team
 * @param GuestTeamID the id of the guest team
 * @param IsPlayed whether or not the match is played
 */
public Match(int MatchID, int MatchRound, int HomeTeamID, int GuestTeamID, boolean IsPlayed) {
```

In Eclipse you can just type `/**` above the constructor and it will generate the Javadoc template automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't write *any*, because it's obvious.

I *would* rename all the parameters to follow Java conventions, though.

Comment: This sort of side slips the question, but still, this is my opinion as well. Look at what the Javadoc looks like in the other answer and see how absurdly useless it is.

Comment: Well its a projekt ive been working on with a group, and our teacher says that we have write javadocs for eceything..
even the obviuos ones. :)

Comment: That's a bad sign. In any case, with proper naming, the Java doc tool will generate essentially the same docs.